# Why dc component I must flow entirely through the load resistance R in buck converter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc-dc-converter, circuit-design, power-electronics, buck

The excerpt below is from Fundamentals of Power Electronics by by Dragan Maksimović and Robert Warren Erickson.
Can anyone explain the why question in the yellow part below? Why dc component I must flow entirely through the load resistance R?

[image]

[image]

Comment: where else is it going to go?

Comment: I consider it as an ideal constant current source, then it can charge up the capacitor. Is there something wrong? Normally we can use current source to charge the capacitor.

Comment: A buck converter is usually configured to be a constant voltage source. The switch has a rather complex control circuit.

Comment: *Normally we can use current source to charge the capacitor* That is true but once that capacitor is charged (to the nominal output voltage) then the current has to go somewhere else.

Comment: If we connect a current source with a capacitor, the capacitor will be charged. So in this case, there is also a current source connected with the capacitor (in parallel with R). By using current divider rule, I can see all the current flow through R but I can't explain it intuitively.

Comment: You're thinking 'initial conditions' when the cap is discharged. Imagine the cap is already charged to Vg - now where does the DC current go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to the question is that they asked about the "DC component".  Capacitors and inductors influence the AC properties of a circuit.  DC implies steady-state, as in no time-varying components.  You can usually think of a circuit as steady-state by replacing inductors with shorts (or low value resistors) and caps as open circuits.  In that case you would have I passing simply through R.

Yes, the capacitor charges initially when switching, but that current is not steady-state, it's time-varying, so it's not part of the DC component.  The AC component, as the question goes on to explain, divides between the cap and the resistor.

Think of the AC and DC components being added together to provide the final result (called superposition).  In the image below you see AC voltage ripple added to DC voltage.  This is for voltage but it would be the same principle for current.

[image]

Comment: I also tried to use superposition but the problem is as below. The current consists of DC and AC parts. The DC part can be considered as an ideal current source. And as we know, an ideal DC current source can flow through (charge up) the capacitor. I think I am having problem with the assumption that average capacitor voltage is constant now.

Comment: You have to think about the circuit after all the energy storage devices (inductors and capacitors) are 'charged', if you are asked about DC properties.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens when there is no output resistor i.e. no output load current. If the capacitor voltage has an average value that is constant i.e. the voltage regulator is doing its job properly then, the only current through the inductor is that which charges and discharges the capacitor. This average value will be zero because, if there was some net average current, then the average voltage on the capacitor must be rising or falling.

That's the no-load scenario and clearly both DC output current is zero (open circuit load) and the average inductor current is zero. By inspection the capacitor average current must also be zero.

Putting a load resistor on means there is an average DC current that is set by the average DC voltage on the capacitor but there is no average DC current that flows into the capacitor providing that the output voltage is stable at some average value.

Comment: I think I have problem with the assumption that average capacitor voltage is constant. If that is the case, then there should be no net current flowing through capacitor during a period. But why is it possible to make that assumption?

Comment: Why do you think the net capacitor current would not be zero?  If you get this circuit running and the switch is going at some fixed frequency and duty cycle, wouldn't you expect the average capacitor voltage to be constant?

Comment: There is current flowing in and out of the capacitor every switching cycle but, if the long term average voltage remains constant (i.e. long enough of a time period to average out ripple voltage) then the average current into the capacitor is zero; current flows in through the inductor and current flows out through the inductor.